# Code not working properly

Tags: loops, python-3.x, for-loop

So its fairly simple. Given a string I want to print out all the letters grammatically correct. With 'an' with vowels and 'a' in all other letters.

I cant seem to do that right now.

```
my_name = 'Alexander'

for l in my_name:
    if l in "A" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u": 
        print("give me an " + l + " !")
    else:
        print('give me a '+l +" !")
```

Problem: 
All the letters are printed out with an "an"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that every time you use `or` you need a **separate conditional**. Otherwise, you are simply evaluating `"e"` which is always `True`.

Just check if it is in a list like so:

```
my_name = 'Alexander'

for l in my_name:
    if l.lower() in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]: #str.lower() is to check regardless of capitalization
        print("give me an " + l + " !")
    else:
        print('give me a '+l +" !")
```

If you check the boolean value of a string, it is always `True`:

```
>>> bool("e")
True
>>>
```

And so the code would always enter the `if`.

---

```
>>> for l in my_name:
...     if l.lower() in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]: #str.lower() is to check regardless of capitalization
...         print("give me an " + l + " !")
...     else:
...         print('give me a '+l +" !")
... 
give me an A !
give me a l !
give me an e !
give me a x !
give me an a !
give me a n !
give me a d !
give me an e !
give me a r !
>>>
```

Comment: `in "aeiou"` looks cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this.

```
my_name = 'Alexander'

for l in my_name:
    if l.lower() in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
        print("give me an " + l + " !")
    else:
        print('give me a '+l +" !")
```

You need to check if the letter is in an array of characters.  If you want a boolean expression then the if condition will have to be

```
if l == "A" or l == "e" or l == "i" or l == "o" or l == "u":
```

Answer (score 0):

It is printing it because the condition `if l in "A" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":` always returns last character "u" and therefore condition goes to true so to solve this you have to write it like this,

```
if l in "A" or l in "e" or l in "i" or l in "o" or l in "u":
```

or you can also write it like this in list,

```
if l in ["A","e","i","o","u"]:
```